# Eclipse jdt formatter configuration to force braces for if else

Tags: java, xml, formatting, eclipse-jdt

I'm trying to set the xml configuration file to force if else statement to always have curly braces but the [docs](https://help.eclipse.org/latest/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjdt%2Fcore%2Fformatter%2FDefaultCodeFormatterConstants.html) don't have any option for that.

How can i do that?

I tried googling but its no where to be found

Comment: What do you mean by "force"? Show a compile error?

Comment: The formatter doesn't ever add code, it only formats what is currently there. You can use "Clean up"  (Preferences > Java > Clean up) to do this - look at the "Code Style" "use blocks in if/while/for/do" settings.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.